# drilling SMT footprints for fitting THT parts

Tags: surface-mount, pcb-assembly, through-hole, drill

I have bought by mistake some THT caps instead of SMD and would like to use them still. They were bought from a supplier who has the bad habit of not answering customer requests. These are 5000h caps, costed me a few bucks.

I guess I could drill the SMT pads and iron solder the parts from above, inserting the soldering tip between the SMT pad and the cap's body. Any reason for not attempting this ?

**edit**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture of the caps and footprints you are wanting to drill? It may be better to bend the leads and solder them to the exposed pads.

Comment: @CalebReister Hmm, I don't know, they are going to be used in a shaky and vibratory environment.

Comment: My main concern is that the pads will probably be torn off after you drill and place pins through them. The holes will be unplated, with no support from the other side of the board. This will put a large amount of stress on the SMD pads.

Comment: @CalebReister That makes sense. maybe I could twist the cap's leads into spirals for more solder grip. A bit of inductance can't hurt, err...

Comment: Depending on the lead and pad sizes, that may do more harm than good. A picture would help.

Comment: @CalebReister added picture

Comment: Actually, the lead spiral will not form an inductor as it will be shorted out by lots of solder. Perhaps it is a viable way.

Answer (score 5):

I totally agree with others that drilling into the pads is a very bad idea; even if there are no conductors beneath, it will most probably lift the remaining parts of the pad. However, I'm quite surprised no one mentioned that THT component leads can simply be bent to turn the component into makeshift SMT component. If the board is part of a small quantity batch or a prototype, I would just simply do this:

[image]

More info on this [here](https://console5.com/wiki/Converting_from_Surface_to_Leaded_Capacitors).

Of course, if it's a large product batch, I agree that cutting losses and doing it properly with SMT components will prove better in the long run.

Comment: indeed, but OP says that the boards are subject to vibration, and in that case I would not do it this way. The proper SMT part is far less likely to pull a pad off over time or just get knocked.

Comment: If vibration was a crucial issue in the given application, I would expect vibration-proof packages and their corresponding footprints to be there in the first place. But in any case, it comes down to whether it is really acceptable or not to do what I suggested for the given batch. As for knocking over, I don't think it's an issue in any case unless it's a bare PCB, hard to say without knowing more about the application.

Comment: Through hole parts are generally pretty good against vibration when mounted normally. (I believe they are specified in some avionics applications, for instance, for that reason.) That might be why the poster decided on through hole for electrolytics (but not for smaller parts). See the first two comments under the OP.

Comment: Of course, but why then not use through hole footprints in the first place? This is why I believe OP's application could be not really critical on vibration. Again, it's very hard to say without any more details.

Comment: This is exactly how the SMT versions of these capacitors are made anyway. The only thing you're missing is the plastic "foot" that helps stabilize the capacitor mechanically, as well as make sure that the leads don't short to the case.

Comment: you're right - he probably should have gone for TH. But personally I would trust an SMD part on an SMD pad more than a TH one with bent leads, in terms of physical security.

Comment: that said - this would still be better than drilling the pads - ugh.

Answer (score 3):

It's horrible. It might be doable but everything depends on on pad and hole sizes. There are so many gotchas:

- how many layers on the board? any ground/power plane? if so forget it.
- can you drill that accurately, over and over? how many caps on how many boards?
- you say the board will be subject to vibration. Even worse.

OK 5000 hour (actually not that much) caps and they cost you something - but weigh this against the costs of damaged boards and field failures.

It sounds like false economy to me. Cut your losses and do it right.